# PHP PDO Firebird charset never changes

Tags: php, pdo, firebird

Connection string is like;

`firebird:dbname=PRODUCTS.GDB;charset=UTF8`

But unicode characters are not correctly returned. I tried changing it to utf-8 with and without dash, small and big letters, to other charsets like ISO8859_9.. All is the same.

Comment: What is the character set of the columns involved? Also could you include the DDL, a sample of the data, expected and received results?

Comment: Columns' character sets are "NONE". Setting connection string to chartset=NONE is not helping. The software client using "NONE" charset is returning correct chars, but not PDO. In browser, if I manually change the charset, it displays correctly. 

It displays like: �ANTA S�YAH
It should display: ÇANTA SİYAH

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using character set `NONE` for the columns. For columns with character set `NONE` all bets are off as Firebird is unable to transliterate to the specified connection character set and will send the data as is. The handling is specific to the client application or driver, some will apply the default system encoding, others will just assume it is in the connection character set they expected (in your case UTF-8), etc. Doing this may even lead to logical data corruption (eg because you are storing it in UTF-8 and another application is retrieving it expecting Windows-1254 or ISO-8859-9).

The fact it may display correct in another application, may be because that application assumes the stored data is in a certain character set and guesses right.

I don't know PHP, nor PDO, but a workaround might be to specify the actual character set of the data (eg `WIN1254` instead of `UTF8`) in the connection string as this may lead to the characters being correctly converted.

However, the only real solution is to create a new database with a default character set other than `NONE`, execute the DDL (and specifying explicit character sets for columns that need to have a different one), and then pump the data from the old to the new database, making sure you apply the right character set conversion(s).

When this is done you will also need to ensure that all applications connecting to this database will use an explicit connection character set.

Comment: Trying to change character set but it's no use. I ran these queries;

`ALTER CHARACTER SET utf8 SET DEFAULT COLLATION utf8` and `ALTER TABLE STOKKART ALTER COLUMN STOK_ADI VARCHAR(60) CHARACTER SET utf8`.

Queries ran with no errors; but charater set is still "NONE" and the utf chars are still broken.

Comment: Well, I used EFS Migration Tool to move to a new DB with a real character set; but couldn't use UTF8. I had to switch to WIN1254 because the client is working only on WIN1254 mode. Now I switched the DB to WIN1254 and client is still working, but PDO still breaks on the browser. If I manually switch the browser's charset for that page; it displays correctly. But database inserts are still broken.

Comment: @Turab then I have no clue what is wrong. You are specifying utf8 as the connection character set?

Comment: I cannot interfere to the charset of the client application, because it's a packed exe. If I specifiy UTF8 as charset, browser app inserts and selects work well and it displays the results correctly. But this time the client software breaks. Client works the same while the charset is `NONE` or `WIN1254`. That is, if I set the charset to WIN1254, client works, but browser breaks although I set the PDO connection string like; `firebird:dbname=database.fdb;charset=WIN1254`. If I manually set the page viewing charset to Windows-1254, browser then displays correctly; but inserts are still broken.

Comment: @Turab you only need to use UTF8 as the connection character set in your web application. If your columns are now WIN1254, Firebird will translate between character sets and the data is stored as WIN1254, so the other client executable should be fine.

Comment: Now the DB is WIN1254, if I set PHP headers to serve content in WIN1254, now both web app and client app displays the results very well. But when it comes to inserts, it fails. Client app never works well with UTF8. Here is an example string; "Müşteri". How inserted string looks like while the db charset is WIN1254 is; "MÃ¼ÅŸteri". And it retrieves back the same both in web app and client app. (Other rows with the same string are ok. Only newly inserted one is problematic.) This is the point where I hate Firebird..

Comment: @Turab it sounds like your columns are still none, or the connection character set is not applied. This should work with Firebird, but as I have never used it from php, I don't know if there are extra things one needs to do.